# Inserting rows from different activity is not being shown in main activity

Tags: android

I have a database helper class that gets all of the rows of a table from a SQLite database. In the onCreate of my Main Activity I am calling that method and populating a ListView with that data.

I have a separate Activity that is getting info from a network and inserting rows into the database. After that is done I am calling finish() and it returns to the Main Activity.

When it returns the inserted rows are not being displayed in the ListView. From debugging, it appears that they are not being returned from the database helper method.

If I close and relaunch the app, the rows show up. If I change the screen orientation, they show up.

Here is my database helper method:

```
public List<Object> getAllObjects() {

        List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_OBJECT,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Object object = cursorToObject(cursor);
            objects.add(object);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        return objects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main `Activity` is *not* newly created, you return to an old instance. In your case, put the update code in the [`onResume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method of your main `Activity`, not in the `onCreate` method.

See the [`Activity` lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for further details on when code is executed.

Comment: I tried that previously and it didn't work. I just tried it again off of your suggestion and it still isn't working :/ I tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the listview adapter and still nothing. Debugging shows it's calling the helper so perhaps it's a cursor issue, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @6thSigma Maybe post the code using `onResume`, including your log calls and the logcat you get?

Comment: I just have datasource.getAllMovies() in the onResume and then I'm calling a getCount() on the cursor. It's returning 0. I pulled the database right after inserting the rows and they are in there. It's almost as if the cursor is not re-querying the database when my activity resumes.

Comment: Can you post that `getAllMovies`, too?

Comment: Oh sorry, getAllMovies is actually getAllObjects I have above. I changed the name in the question to make it more generic.

Comment: @6thSigma not sure what's wrong then. I could imagine there's something in the surrounding code, or you encounter a strange bug, or we both are blind ;)